# From a CSV file get the file header and a portion of the file based on starting and ending line number parameters using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, file, csv, import, export-to-csv

So I have a very huge CSV file, the first line has the column headers.  I want to keep the first line as a header and add a portion of the file from the file's mid-section or perhaps the end. I'm also trying to select only a few of the columns from the file. And finally, it would be great if the solution also changed the file delimiter from a comma to a tab.

I'm aiming for a solution that's a one-liner or perhaps 2?

**Non-working Code version 30 ...**

```
Get-Content -Tail 100 filename.csv | Export-Csv -Delimiter "`t" -NoTypeInformation -Path .\filename_out.csv
```

I'm trying to get a better grip on PowerShell. So far, so good but I'm not quite there yet. But trying to solve such challenges are helping me (and hopefully others) build a good collection of coding idioms. (FYI - the boss is trying PowerShell due to our efforts so.)

Comment: Start with using [`Import-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-7) instead of `Get-Content`.

Comment: @iRon Maybe you could add this as the answer?  Only issue, my 'solution' below does not get a middle chunk of file only the end ... thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

OK thanks to iRon tip. Import-CSV defaults to comma separated, the Select-Object -Property get the columns I want, the select -Last gets the last 200 rows, and the Export-CSV changes the delimiter to a tab:

```
Import-Csv iarf.csv |
  Select-Object -Property Id,Name,RecordTypeId,CreatedDate | 
   select -Last 200 | 
     Export-Csv -Delimiter "`t" -NoTypeInformation -Path .\iarf100props6.csv
```

Comment: Except you can't break your lines like that. You can have a pipeline at the end of a line and continue on the line below but you cannot start a line with a pipeline character.

Comment: Thanks I was trying to make it look better here.

Comment: I've reformatted the code to work syntactically while still being readable. @SagePourpre, note that PowerShell _Core_ now _does_ support placing the `|` on the (very) _next_ line. As an aside: there is a - lively debated - [RFC](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-RFC/pull/179) to also make spreading a _single_ command across multiple lines for readability easier, as a more natural alternative to splatting.

Answer (score 0):

[iRon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1701026/iron) provided the crucial pointer: Using `Import-Csv` rather than `Get-Content` allows you to retrieve arbitrary ranges from the original file *as objects*, if selected via `Select-Object`, and exporting these objects again via `Export-Csv` automatically includes a header line whose column names are the input objects' property names, as initially derived from the input file's header line.

In order to select an arbitrary range of rows, combine [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object)'s  `-Skip` and `-First` parameters:

- To only get rows from the *beginning*, use just `-First $count`:
- To only get rows from the *end*, use just `-Last $count`
- To get rows in a given *range*, use just `-Skip $startRowMinus1 -First $rangeRowCount`

For instance, the following command extracts rows `10` through `30`:

```
Import-Csv iarf.csv | 
  Select-Object -Property Id,Name,RecordTypeId,CreatedDate -Skip 9 -First 20 |
    Export-Csv -Delimiter "`t" -NoTypeInformation -Path .\iarf100props6.csv
```